# Report Hyperlink to a field on a custom page

Tags: acumatica

We have a custom page in our Acumatica to enter Work Orders.  The first field on the page is obviously the WO number.  I have the WO number on many of the custom reports we have made.  I tried to hyperlink to the WO number on one of my reports by changing the NavigateMethod property to Server as I have done for the SO number many times. The WO displays on the report as a hyperlink but clicking on it produces nothing.  Right clicking and choosing open in new tab opens a tab for about.blank.  What do we have to do so that the WO number will produce the same behavior in the report as, say, the SO number from the Sales Order Entry page?

Comment: Do you have PXSelectorAttribute on WO number field? You should have one to make navigation work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the above solution won't work (most probably if you route to your own custom screen), 
I think the proper implementation is using Main.aspx? in the Navigate URL
and no need of Server navigate method

So your navigate URL will be for Standard Acumatica screen (Invoices and Memos-AR301000)
Navigate Method: Client

Navigate URL: 'Main.aspx?ScreenId=AR301000&DocType=INV&RefNbr='+ [ARInvoice.RefNbr]

Target:either main or _blank

follow the same way to compose the URL for custom screens as well

Answer (score 0):

On a TextBox field use the following three properties:
NavigateMethod, NavigateUrl and Target

Here is an example for a PO:

NavigateMethod: Server

NavigateUrl: ='?ScreenId=PO301000&OrderNbr=' + [POOrder.OrderNbr]

Target: _blank

[image]

You can craft the NavigateUrl by going to the page you want to redirect to in Acumatica and selecting the key (ex: the WO field). Then you can copy the URL param from the browser URL bar to your report NavigateURL property. Replace hardcoded key with the WO parameter in your report by concatenating it in NavigateUrl formula.

Target is the standard hyperlink target property, '_blank' will open the link in a new page.

Target reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_form_target.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still is not working.
NavigateMethod  Server
Navigate URL ='https://acumatica.silcotek.com/acumaticasandbox/(W(2))/?CompanyID=SandboxSilcotek&ScreenId=MN100003&Id=' + [EMPWorkOrder.Id]
Target _blank
When I click the hyperlink, nothing happens

Comment: URL ='https://acumatica.silcotek.com/acumaticasandbox/(W(2))/?CompanyID=SandboxSilcotek&ScreenId=MN100003&Id=' + [EMPWorkOrder.Id]

Comment: You put the domain in the link. You should put the URL Param. URL param starts with question mark symbol like in my example above: ?ScreenId=xxxx.... You should also remove unnecessary params like company ID. Keep ScreenID and field keys only.

Comment: Not sure why it keeps editing my url,   &ScreenId=MN100003&Id=' + [EMPWorkOrder.Id]

Comment: Don't bother about it, this is just poor formatting on SO semi-column. Just remove domain from your link and unnecessary param. It should look like my example above ='?ScreenId=XXXXX&Id=' + [EMPWorkOrder.Id]

Comment: I tried that as well, but I just tried again,  URL  ='?ScreenId=MN100003&Id=' + [EMPWorkOrder.Id]
Still nothing

Comment: Can you post the browser URL that is working to Paste BIN and post the link to Paste BIN here in the comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145063/discussion-between-hb-acumatica-and-georgem).